# Como usar o querySelectorAll() para procurar por tag especifica derivada de um elemento que tem uma classe x?

Tags: javascript, dom, elementos

Alguém saberia me ajudar a usar o `.querySelectorAll()` para encontrar todos os elementos de parágrafo derivados dos elementos que possuam uma `classe` x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se quer encontrar todos os parágrafos `<p>` dentro de um elemento com uma classe `x` você usa o seletor `".x p"`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".x p");
```

Se quer apenas os elementos `<p>` filhos-diretos, use `".x > p"`:

```
document.querySelectorAll(".x > p");
```

**Todos os elementos dentro da classe:**

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".x p");
for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   console.log(els[x]);
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
   <p>paragrafo 1</p>
   <p>paragrafo 2</p>
   <div class="y">
      <p>paragrafo 3</p>
      <div class="z">
         <p>paragrafo 4</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="x">
   <p>paragrafo 5</p>
   <p>paragrafo 6</p>
   <div class="y">
      <p>paragrafo 7</p>
      <div class="z">
         <p>paragrafo 8</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

**Apenas os filhos diretos:**

```js
var els = document.querySelectorAll(".x > p");
for(var x=0; x<els.length; x++){
   console.log(els[x]);
}
```

```html
<div class="x">
   <p>paragrafo 1</p>
   <p>paragrafo 2</p>
   <div class="y">
      <p>paragrafo 3</p>
      <div class="z">
         <p>paragrafo 4</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>

<div class="x">
   <p>paragrafo 5</p>
   <p>paragrafo 6</p>
   <div class="y">
      <p>paragrafo 7</p>
      <div class="z">
         <p>paragrafo 8</p>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Considere *filhos-diretos* os elementos no primeiro nível dentro da hierarquia do *elemento-pai*.

Comment: obrigado mano, testei aqui e finalmente conseguir.